# How can I remove space/gaps between continuous x-values in geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, geom-raster

I am working with some time-frequency decomposed EEG data and want to produce a spectrogram-like figure using ggplot2. But, I end up with blank spaces between each of my time points.

```
Data <- read.csv(url("https://www.dropbox.com/s/al3cygigm86mr3s/Test_Spec_Data.csv?dl=0"))
```

If I create a vanilla geom_raster I get gaps in the x and y data:

```
ggplot(Data,aes(Times,Frequency)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = ERSP))
```

[image: Default]

If I make `Frequency` a factor, it fills in the y gap; but, the gaps along the x-axis remain:

```
  ggplot(Data,aes(Times,factor(round(Frequency,digits=1)))) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = ERSP))
```

[image: With y as factor]

I can eliminate the gaps by making `Times` a factor.

[image]

But, managing `scale_x_discrete` with this many data points is cumbersome (note the x-axis labels). Also, these time data are continuous and not really factor-like.

`geom_raster` doesn't have a `width` argument like `geom_bar` and I can't see anything similar in the `geom_raster` documentation.

Is there a way to keep `Times` as continuous but remove the gaps between observations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are gaps because there are not enough data (or more precisely, they are not evenly spaced).

Your "factor" transformation remove the gap because it remove the X or Y axis parts where data are missing. See in Y axis: ticks are evenly spaces but values are not (8.5-8.1=0.4, while 11.3-10.7=0.6, where you have you biggest gap).

I can see two solutions:

- Interpolate data so your source data are evenly spaced
- Use `geom_tile` instead of `geom_raster` and specify `width` and `height` parameters to "expand" your tiles and fill the gaps, as explained in [the fourth example of the doc](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_tile.html).