# Removing/ smoothing x axis gaps in ggplot2 heat map

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, heatmap

I am transitioning from using a heatmap created using the lattice "levelplot" to one using ggplot2, but I'm running into an issue in how the two packages deal with uneven x-axis variables.

Here is my data with an uneven time series:

```
MyTimes<-as.POSIXct(c(rep("2020-10-01 10:15:00",3),rep("2020-10-01 11:25:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 11:45:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 12:23:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 14:15:00",3),
                    rep("2020-10-01 15:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 16:32:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 16:20:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 18:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-01 19:15:00",3),                      
                    rep("2020-10-02 10:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-02 11:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-02 12:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-02 13:33:00",3), rep("2020-10-02 20:15:00",3),                    
                   rep("2020-10-03 10:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-03 15:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-03 19:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-05 10:15:00",3), rep("2020-10-05 12:15:00",3)))


MyY<-rep(seq(1,3),20)
MyValue<-runif(60, min = 0, max = 25) 
MyData<-data.frame(MyTimes, MyY, MyValue)
```

And resulting plot:

```
library(lattice)
levelplot(MyValue  ~ MyTimes * MyY,
          data = MyData,
          ylim=c(3,0),
          aspect=0.4)
```

Using the above levelplot code, the plot was "too smoothed" in that it was smoothing over large time gaps. I was able to fix this by inserting blocks of NA values that broke up the time-series plot, so that only smaller gaps were smoothed over. I realize there is some judgment on my part as to what constitutes a "large time gap", but I'm OK manually deciding this like so:

```
GapTimes<-as.POSIXct(c(rep("2020-10-01 19:16:00",3),rep("2020-10-02 20:16:00",3),rep("2020-10-03 19:16:00",3)))
MyGapY<-rep(seq(1,3),3)
MyGapValues<-rep(NA,9)
Gap<-data.frame(GapTimes,MyGapY,MyGapValues)
colnames(Gap)<-colnames(MyData)


MyData2<-rbind(MyData,Gap)
```

So now when I plot my heatmap, I have the small gaps smoothed over, and the larger ones are not,

```
levelplot(MyValue  ~ MyTimes * MyY,
          data = MyData2,
          ylim=c(3,0),
          aspect=0.4)
```

What I'd like to do is switch over to a Ggplot2 heatmap, but the below Ggplot2 code has zero smoothing, and the large amount of white space (even between the smallest gaps) makes it difficult to visualize change over time

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = MyData2,aes(x=MyTimes, y=MyY)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = MyValue), interpolate=TRUE)+
  scale_y_reverse(lim=c(3,0))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits=c(0,25), colors=c("blue","red"),oob = scales::squish)+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Is it possible to reproduce the above levelplot smoothing using a similar Ggplot2 based method?

This is a similar question to this one, which did not seem to have a satisfying answer:
[How can I remove space/gaps between continuous x-values in geom_raster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029650/how-can-i-remove-space-gaps-between-continuous-x-values-in-geom-raster)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this would be to calculate the tiles you want to plot as rectangles and draw them with `geom_rect`. You could even set a threshold to allow you to define a different but consistent maximum gap between consecutive measurements:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Set maximum number of hours that will be "filled in" between measurements
max_smooth <- 12

MyData %>%
  group_by(MyY) %>%
  arrange(MyTimes, by_group = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(right = as.numeric(difftime(lead(MyTimes), MyTimes, units = "hour")),
         right = as.POSIXct(ifelse(right > max_smooth, 
                                   MyTimes + lubridate::hours(max_smooth),
                                   lead(MyTimes)),
                           origin = "1970-01-01"),
         top = MyY, bottom = MyY - 1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(MyTimes, MyY)) +
  geom_rect(aes(xmin = MyTimes, xmax = right, ymin = bottom, ymax = top,
                fill = MyValue)) +
  scale_y_reverse(lim = c(3, 0)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(limits = c(0, 25), 
                       colors = c("blue", "red"), oob = scales::squish) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
#> Warning: Removed 3 rows containing missing values (geom_rect).
```

[image]

---

**Data**

```r
set.seed(1)

MyData <- data.frame(MyTimes = as.POSIXct(rep(paste0("2020-10-", 
                                 c("01 10:15:00", "01 11:25:00", "01 11:45:00",
                                   "01 12:23:00", "01 14:15:00", "01 15:15:00", 
                                   "01 16:32:00", "01 16:20:00", "01 18:15:00", 
                                   "01 19:15:00", "02 10:15:00", "02 11:15:00", 
                                   "02 12:15:00", "02 13:33:00", "02 20:15:00",
                                   "03 10:15:00", "03 15:15:00", "03 19:15:00",
                                   "05 10:15:00", "05 12:15:00")), each = 3)),
                      MyY = rep(1:3, 20),
                      MyValue = runif(60, 0, 25))
```